# Image brings back null JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to capture the image in this link from DOM but I keep getting `null`.
Please help: :[image: The site is aliexpress.com]

Here is my code;

```
t.image = document.querySelector('.item-group tbody a img').getAttribute("src");
```

DOM:

[image: The DOM]

Will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the querySelector returning the correct element (Write it in the console and check if it really find the img tag) you need to replace the get `getAttribute("src");` with just src, so it will look like this:

```
t.image = document.querySelector('.item-group tbody a img').src;
```

Comment: It just returns the line of code at the console, so I cant see if it finds the img tag.

Comment: brings back undefined